# NoHostAvailable:, In elassandra on insert query with Network Topology Strategy

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra, cqlsh, elassandra

In elassandra on insert query with Network Topology Strategy it show's 'no host available'.

```
cqlsh>CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS twitter WITH replication={ 'class':'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'dc1':'1' };

cqlsh>CREATE TABLE twitter.user (
   name text,
   attrs map<text,text>,
   PRIMARY KEY (name)
);

cqlsh>INSERT INTO twitter.user (name,attrs) VALUES ('bob',{'email':'bob@gmail.com','firstname':'bob'});
```

[image]
nodetool status[image]

another keyspace using same dc, show's this
[image]

Comment: show use the output of nodetool status

Comment: sachin@user-PC:~/elassandraDemo/elassandra-2.4.2/bin$ ./nodetool status twitter
Datacenter: DC1
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  127.0.0.1  186.72 KB  8            0.0%              089a9ce4-7676-4b14-9773-58aa5913fa34  r1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Change data center name of your keyspace to `DC1`**

```
ALTER KEYSPACE twitter WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'DC1' : 1};
```

> Data Center name is case sensitive.

---

**Edited**

Two replication strategies are available:

- SimpleStrategy: Use for a single data center only. If you ever intend more than one data center, use the NetworkTopologyStrategy.
- NetworkTopologyStrategy: Highly recommended for most deployments because it is much easier to expand to multiple data centers when required by future expansion.

Comment: is datacenter or replication is same thing or not?

Comment: No. For each keyspace replication can be configured for each data center

Comment: is that possible to work elasticsearch on simpleStrategy?

Comment: @SachinArora yes, it is possible.  and check the edited answer

Comment: It's work well with DC1 but when we created another keyspace with the same DC1 then it's not worked.

Comment: pls check the question again, I added another further problem index not found

Comment: @SachinArora the problem you mention is not about cassandra. It's the elasticsearch. elasticsearch index not found.

Answer (score 0):

`'dc1'` at the time of creating the keyspace should be the Datacenter name when you use `nodetool status`